# What is the best way to display Nested Arrays in JSON Objects in Angular2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

**Let us assume my object is Look like**

```
   {
       firstName: 'John',
       lastName: 'Smith',
       dob: '12/12/1980'
    }
```

**I could easily go with like this**

```
{{person.firstName}} 
{{person.lastName }} 
{{person.dob | date}}
```

**But i want to display my server response Nested Arrays in JSON Objects Like this**

```
{
"firstName":"John",
"lastName": "Smith",
"dob": "12/12/1980",
 "cars":
    { 
      "name":"BMW", 
      "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] 
    }
}
```

**how could i display it? if i go with this {{person.cars.name}}, i am getting an TypeError "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".**

Comment: That means person.cars is undefined, and that the JSON you actually have is not the one you posted. Note that you're not asking anything about arrays here. cars is a nested object.

Comment: Maybe there are objects that doesn't have the `cars` key (or maybe it's undefined).. so use the safe navigation operator: `{{person.cars?.name}}`.

Comment: @developer033 yeah, it's working when using the safe navigation operator: {{person.cars?.name}}, thank you...

Comment: @developer033 Thank you....

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand very well your question, but:

If you want to navigate through your nested object, use:

`{{person?.car?.name}}`

Because maybe some persons won't have a car.

If you want to display / dump the object as a JSON, use the `json` pipe:

```
{{ person | json }}
```

**Clarification of `?.` operator:**

The `?.` operator allows you not to throw an error if `a` in example is `null`:

```
a.b // Error shown
a?.b // No error
```

Documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator

I confirm that it can be used when navigating through object properties:

```
a?.b?.c // Is allowed
```

Cit from documentation:

> It works perfectly with long property paths such as `a?.b?.c?.d`.

Comment: yes actually it's only one person data. when i log it {{person.car | json }} it's working.

Comment: when i display it {{person.car.name}} i got a TypeError. thankyou @SrAxi . now i understood {{person?.car.name}} it's working.

Comment: AFAIK if you have `person?.car...` you need `person?.car?.name`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I never had to use a double. But I didn't know about that, it makes sense. If the `person` has a `car` but the `car` doesn't have a `name`... Yes, Will change it. But I'm stil trying to guess what the OP really wants! If your original question with the `json` pipe or navigate through the object...

Comment: It could be that Angular just drops the whole expression after `person` is `null`, but if `person` isn't null, but `person.car` is, it will cause an error. I only use Dart and here `person?.car.name` would cause an exception when `person` is null (they consider changing this though).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I thought that `person?.car.name` won't crash if `person` is `null`, but would crash if `car` is null, no? The `?.` operator in `person?.car.name` is safeguarding us from crashing when `person` is null, right?

Comment: As mentioned, I never actually tried this in Angular TS and I believe you when you say this works for you (in Dart it would cause an exception though)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You were right about the `a?.b?.c` usage! And I confirm that `person?.car.name` avoids errors when `person` is `null`, not when `car` is `null`. Check my update! Thanks for the tips and the chat! ;=)

Answer (score 0):

`{{person|json}}` will out output the full json object to the page. To view it in the layout you have shown, wrap it in a `pre` tag like this:

```
<pre>{{person|json}}</pre>
```

If the `person.cars` property is present then it will be shown as you have displayed.